# display: inline-block height

Tags: css, alignment, height

Is there a css-way to make images align to one (bottom) line, with the text aligned to the top? In other words, how to give these `<li>` elements equal height? min-height is a bad idea 'cause amount of letters is unknown, and overflow:hidden is also cannot be used as users should see the full text.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="text">Some random text.<div class="image"></div></div></li>
    <li><div class="text">Some random text.<div class="image"></div></div></li>
    <li><div class="text">Some random text.<div class="image"></div></div></li>
    <li><div class="text">Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.<div class="image"></div></div></li>
    <li><div class="text">Some random text.<div class="image"></div></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li div.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

li div.image {
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m2vnan1/)

Comment: is this you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/9m2vnan1/1/ float and vertical-align do not go along.

Comment: @GCyrillus no, I need the text aligned to top and image to bottom.

Comment: okay, inbricated flex li/ .text  might be a solution  https://jsfiddle.net/9m2vnan1/3/

Comment: @GCyrillus flex is a solution, but lacks of browser support. Thanks anyway, your example works.

Comment: flex is avalaible in ie10+ , table in IE8+ but doesn't wrap, IE -8 ? massive javascript !! :) ( BTW autoprefixer should be used also if you plan flex, else it is a nghtmare prefixing flex rules ... )

Comment: ... but defaut inline-block/inline-table; is a fine fallback, isn't it ? https://jsfiddle.net/9m2vnan1/4/ https://jsfiddle.net/9m2vnan1/5/

Comment: caniuse.com says it's buggy even in IE11. As to your last example - it's the same as mine but aligned to the bottom. But what I need - is to get rid of white spaces, so that the height of items would be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try without a list and use display: table to make them all the same height. Since we know the image is 200px tall, we're going to absolutely position it to the bottom of the box, with 200px of padding added.

```
<div class="boxes">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text. text text text text text</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
</div> 
   <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
    <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="box">
     <span>Here's some random text. Mooooooooooore Text. And more</span>
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/pandit-ravi-shankars-96th-birthday-6265541272535040-hp2x.jpg" />
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here's the css

```
boxes{
  display: table;
}
.row{
  display: table-row;
}
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 200px; // making space for our image
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
}
span{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5mk352r/2/

Comment: in this example the items are not transferred to new line, they should do that automatically like with inline-box or float:left.

Comment: @Martin yes they are. everything wrapper in a <div class="row"> </div> is one line. That's what display: table-row; does.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand: when I change window width, elements don't transfer to the new line. I need the behaviour similar to "float:left" or "inline-block" (it can be seen in my example). In your example it's always 2 items at row, and besides they decrease their width when the screen width is too small.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. This solution won't work for u then lol